# Can't create alias for VPC API Gateway endpoint in Route 53

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, vpc-endpoint

I've created a private hosted zone within my VPC called '**execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com**'.  This is set up with an Alias record pointing to a VPC endpoint, which I've associated with my API.

The alias record has the name '***myAPIname*.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com**'.

This works.  I can log onto EC2 instances in my VPC and make a CURL request and get a response.

I want to set up a couple of aliases for the same service.  I've tried creating a record '***london*.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com**' as an alias to the record above.

When I make CURL requests to this new URL, I get a 'forbidden' message.  How do I fix this?  Is it something I need to change in Route 53, or back in API Gateway?

Comment: Update: I've since discovered that aliases for an existing record only work in N.Virginia - I've tried it there too and still get the same error.  I've also tried creating an alias directly pointing at the endpoint and I still get the problem.